# Numpy isfinite typeerror

Tags: python, numpy

I know I'm doing it wrong but I don't see how to do it right. In my executing code, the series I have comes from a large dataframe that I've done a groupby on. In the real code, the assignment happens in a loop as select various slices from the series.

The code below results in TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input type. I'm positive that this is due to a reference, not a copy or something on that line, but I'm just not good enough in Python to understand how to fix it.

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.ion()
period = 36
ward_dates = pd.date_range(start=pd.datetime.today(), freq='M', periods=period)
list_size = 6
ward_counts = [[] for i in range(list_size)]
for idx in range(list_size):
    current_list = [np.random.randint(0, 500000) for r in range(period)]
    ward_counts[idx] = current_list
plt.stackplot(ward_dates, ward_counts)
plt.close('all')

units = np.random.choice(['U1', 'U2', 'U3'], size=period)
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([units, ward_dates])
s1 = pd.Series([np.random.randint(0, 5000) for r in range(period)], index=index)

ward_counts = [[] for i in range(3)]
l1 = [int(x) for x in s1.loc['U1'].values]
ward_counts[0] = l1
l1 = [int(x) for x in s1.loc['U2'].values]
ward_counts[1] = l1
l1 = [int(x) for x in s1.loc['U3'].values]
ward_counts[2] = l1
plt.stackplot(ward_dates, ward_counts)
```

The first stackplot works just fine. The second fails. I know therefore the issue is in grabbing the values. The resulting lists both LOOK identical (ints with the same number of values) but the second fails.

I've looked at slicing, deepcopy, etc. but they continue to fail, so the fundamental problem is my lack of understanding. I'm also sure this is a duplicate of many others but i just don't grasp the issue.

**Update**

Here is the trackback

> File
>   "C:/Users/dgrawroc/PycharmProjects/fs_admin_reports/fs_admin_reports/oldstuff.py",
>   line 47, in main
>       plt.stackplot(ward_dates, ward_counts)   File "C:\Users\dgrawroc\Documents\Anaconda3\envs\m2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py",
>   line 3326, in stackplot
>       ret = ax.stackplot(x, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\dgrawroc\Documents\Anaconda3\envs\m2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib__init__.py",
>   line 1811, in inner
>       return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\dgrawroc\Documents\Anaconda3\envs\m2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_axes.py",
>   line 4443, in stackplot
>       return mstack.stackplot(self, x, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\dgrawroc\Documents\Anaconda3\envs\m2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\stackplot.py",
>   line 113, in stackplot
>       **kwargs))   File "C:\Users\dgrawroc\Documents\Anaconda3\envs\m2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib__init__.py",
>   line 1811, in inner
>       return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\dgrawroc\Documents\Anaconda3\envs\m2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_axes.py",
>   line 4608, in fill_between
>       y2 = ma.masked_invalid(self.convert_yunits(y2))   File "C:\Users\dgrawroc\Documents\Anaconda3\envs\m2\lib\site-packages\numpy\ma\core.py",
>   line 2293, in masked_invalid
>       condition = ~(np.isfinite(a)) TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely
>   coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Comment: Forgot to add i'm on Numpy 1.10.4 and python 3.5 if that makes a difference

Comment: I don't see any `isfinite` call ... could you provide the complete Traceback? Also it is recommended to [edit] the question rather than providing additional details as comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code does the same thing, it selects from the dataframe and then displays the selection in a stackplot.
I think the error was pretty cryptic and difficult to figure out but it did lead me to write better code

Here is the working code:

```
    period = 36
    first_month = datetime.datetime(2013,  1,1)
    last_month = datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 1)
    ward_dates1 = pd.date_range(start=first_month, freq='M', periods=period)

    units = np.random.choice(['U1', 'U2', 'U3'], size=period)
    index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([units, ward_dates1])
    s1 = pd.Series([np.random.randint(0, 5000) for r in range(period)], index=index)

    t1 = s1.loc['U1']
    t2 = s1.loc['U2']
    t3 = s1.loc['U3']

    t1r = t1.reindex(ward_dates1, fill_value=0)
    t2r = t2.reindex(ward_dates1, fill_value=0)
    t3r = t3.reindex(ward_dates1, fill_value=0)

    tall = np.vstack((t1r, t2r, t3r))
    plt.stackplot(ward_dates1, tall)
```